# How to Give back a DataGridView in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So, I have a project in which I allow editing of a DatagridView in a separate Form. I pass in the DatagridView object and its parent container to the constructor of the new Form.

This works well and I can edit the grid that way.  But when I try to give it back by changing its parent back to the original form, I get this error :

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'
```

Now both MenuItem, and Manual Entry directly inherit from Form.

Here is my code that takes the DataGridView from the original form (which works correctly)

```
public partial class ManualEntry : Form
{
    private Data d;
    DataGridView DataView;
    MenuItem mi;

    public ManualEntry(DataGridView ExcelDisplay, Data d, MenuItem menuItem)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Take the Datagridview from the MenuItem.

        DataView = ExcelDisplay;
        DataView.Parent = this;
        mi = menuItem;
        this.d = d;
        this.DataView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.DataView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 76);
        this.DataView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(237, 211);
        this.DataView.TabIndex = 5;
        this.DataView.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.DataView_CellContentClick);
    }
```

Now here is me trying to give it back. and of course it produces the error above.

```
    private void FinishButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //move the datagridview back to the original form and give its old size,shape, and position back.

        DataView.Parent = mi;
        this.DataView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.DataView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 167);
        this.DataView.Name = "ExcelDisplay";
        this.DataView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 256);
        this.DataView.TabIndex = 7;
        this.Close();
    }
```

I have also tried casting which does not work either.

```
 DataView.Parent = (System.Windows.Forms.Control)mi;
```

**Update**
This shows that MenuItem is a Form as well.

```
public partial class MenuItem : Form
{
```

Comment: you have assign `DataView.Parent` to `MenuItem` but not a `Form`??

Comment: MenuItem is a Form, just like ManualEntry is.

Comment: so you have name your `Form` as `MenuItem`, and from error message, .NET interpret as `System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem`, maybe you can try to change your `MenuItem` to `yournamespace.MenuItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This shows that MenuItem is a Form as well.

Well, you have not convinced the compiler.  You can tell from the error message that it thinks that your "mi" variable is a System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.  Do **not** use .NET class names for your own types, that just makes your life harder to troubleshoot bugs like this.  Don't use variable names like "d" either.  Choosing good names is a Very Important programmer's job.

The proper way is to preserve the control's Parent property so you can set it back.  Roughly:

```
public partial class ManualEntry : Form
{
    private Data DataViewData;
    private DataGridView DataView;
    private Point DataViewLocation;
    private Control DataViewParent;

    public ManualEntry(DataGridView ExcelDisplay, Data data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataViewData = data;
        this.DataView = ExcelDisplay;
        this.DataViewLocation = ExcelDisplay.Location;
        this.DataViewParent = ExcelDisplay.Parent;
        this.DataView.Parent = this;
        // etc...
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
        if (!e.Cancel) {
            DataView.Parent = this.DataViewParent;
            DataView.Location = this.DataViewLocation;
            // etc..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to cast ExcelDisplay.Parent as a Form to get it to work, but otherwise it worked. Thank you.